# how to send actions as plain object?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

making delete request to mongodb database and getting an error message action must be plain object. but if i refresh the store object is deleted. but i want do it live. i have implmented get edit and create request using the same method but when using delete its not happening. what i am doing wrong.import React from "react";

error message : redux.js:278 Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions.

i am dipatching the action from post.js button component  as onClick={() => dispatch(deletePost(post._id))}

```
   const Post = ({ post, setCurrentId }) => {
     const classes = useStyles();
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
   
     const editHandeler = () => {
       setCurrentId(post._id);
     };
   
     return (
       <Card className={classes.card}>
         <CardMedia
           className={classes.media}
           image={
             post.selectedFile ||
             "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/194400/49531010-48dad180-f8b1-11e8-8d89-1e61320e1d82.png"
           }
           title={post.title}
         />
         <div className={classes.overlay}>
           <Typography variant="h6">{post.creator}</Typography>
           <Typography variant="body2">
             {moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}
           </Typography>
         </div>
         <div className={classes.overlay2}>
           <Button style={{ color: "white" }} size="small" onClick={editHandeler}>
             <MoreHorizIcon fontSize="default" />
           </Button>
         </div>
         <div className={classes.details}>
           <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="h2">
             {post.tags.map((tag) => `#${tag} `)}
           </Typography>
         </div>
         <Typography
           className={classes.title}
           gutterBottom
           variant="h5"
           component="h2"
         >
           {post.title}
         </Typography>
         <CardContent>
           <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
             {post.message}
           </Typography>
         </CardContent>


         <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
           <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {}}>
             <ThumbUpAltIcon fontSize="small" /> Like {post.likeCount}{" "}
           </Button>
           <Button
             size="small"
             color="primary"
             onClick={() => dispatch(deletePost(post._id))}
           >
             <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" /> Delete
           </Button>
         </CardActions>
       </Card>
     );
   };
   
   export default Post;
```

delete pos function

```
export const deletePost = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    await api.deletePost(id);

    dispatch({ type: DELETE, payload: id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

api

```
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/posts";

export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(url);
export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);
export const updatePost = (id, updatedPost) =>
  axios.patch(`${url}/${id}`, updatedPost);

export const deletePost = (id) => axios.delete(`${url}/${id}`);
```

reducer

```
    import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, LIKE } from "../actions/constants";

const reducer = (posts = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ALL:
      return action.payload;
    case CREATE:
      return [...posts, action.payload];
    case UPDATE:
      return posts.map((post) =>
        post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post
      );
    case DELETE:
      return posts.filter((post) => post.id !== action.payload);

    default:
      return posts;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

store

```
     import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { reducers } from "./rootreducer";
import { applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const store = configureStore(
  { reducer: reducers },
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

rootreducer

```
export const reducers = combineReducers({
posts: posts,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `configureStore` API incorrectly. [`configureStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#parameters) API from `@reduxjs/toolkit` only accept a single configuration object parameter.

By default, `configureStore` adds some middleware to the Redux store setup automatically. It adds `redux-thunk` by default, so you don't need to add it again using `applyMiddleware`.

I suggest you follow the [tutorials#quick-start](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start).